# How to set selected option by optgroup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following select :

```
<select name="pricelist_product[]" id="pricelist_product">
  <option value="error" disabled="disabled">SELECT PRODUCT</option>
  <optgroup label="Cellcom" id="1">
    <option value="70">75</option>"
    <option value="125">125</option>
    <option value="199">199</option>
    <option value="5">card bonus 5</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Orange" id="2">
    <option value="70"> 70</option>
    <option value="130"> 130</option>
    <option value="135"> 135 </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Now this is just a simplification, in reality I may have a situation in which options from different groups have the same value.

Now what I did is defer them using the ID of the `optgroup` which is a nice hack but I'm encountering problems as to how I can set a selected option by group. I have the following code:

```
$('#prices_table tbody tr:last').children().eq(0).children()
  .val(item.product_id).attr('selected','selected');
```

Now `item.product_id` contains the value, which of course can set the wrong one. I have a 2D array which contains the values like this:

```
values[item.provider_id][item.product_id]
```

Where the first ID is the `optgroup` id and the second is  the value. How can I achieve this ? I found no information on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var groupId = "1";
    var value = "70";

    $("#pricelist_product #'" + groupId +  "' option[value='" + value + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention it has id only for css, i have many select options in the page that it why i addressed with the above selectors.

Comment: Not sure of what you mean by that :/

Comment: meaning i cn't use `#pricelist_product` as a selector

Comment: So, you can select only starting by the optgroup id? If that's so, try this: $("optgroup#'" + groupId +  "' option[value='" + value + "']").prop("selected", true);

Comment: Well i've mixed up something from your examples and it got me to the right direction and i got it to work, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#pricelist_product > optgroup[id='" + item.provider_id +"']").find("option[value='" + item.product_id + "']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: I've forgot to mention it has id only for css, i have many select options in the page that it why i addressed with the above selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way:

`$(yourInputSelector).val(item.product_id);`

Comment: Please post complete answers only. Do not answer in a way that requires clarification from the OP. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.